# How to change classes labels order in a segmentation mask

Tags: label, mask, image-segmentation

I wonder if it's possible to change class labels in a segmentation mask. Suppose I have masks, where the classes order is like that: 0 - class A, 1 - class B, 2 - background. Is there a way to change it to: 0 - background, 1 - class A, 2 - class B?

This is my code:
Now my mask is like: 0 - background, 1 - ground glass, 2 - consolidation, 3 - lung other. What I want: 0 - ground glass, 1 - consolidation, 2 - lung other, 3 - background.

Before changing:

```
i = 31
fig, axes = plt.subplots(2, 2, figsize=(10, 8))
axes[0, 0].imshow(mask_four[i, :, :, 0])
axes[0, 0].set_title('Background')
axes[0, 1].imshow(mask_four[i, :, :, 1])
axes[0, 1].set_title('Ground glass')
axes[1, 0].imshow(mask_four[i, :, :, 2])
axes[1, 0].set_title('Consolidation')
axes[1, 1].imshow(mask_four[i, :, :, 3])
axes[1, 1].set_title('Lung other')
```

Output:
[image]

Changing:

```
lut = torch.tensor([1, 2, 3, 0])
test_mask = mask_four[31]
test_mask2 = lut[test_mask.long()]

fig, axes = plt.subplots(2, 2, figsize=(10, 8))
axes[0, 0].imshow(test_mask2[:, :, 0])
axes[0, 1].imshow(test_mask2[:, :, 1])
axes[1, 0].imshow(test_mask2[:, :, 2])
axes[1, 1].imshow(test_mask2[:, :, 3])
```

Output 2:
[image]

This is test_mask:

```
tensor([[[1., 0., 0., 0.],
         [1., 0., 0., 0.],
         [1., 0., 0., 0.],
         ...,
         [1., 0., 0., 0.],
         [1., 0., 0., 0.],
         [1., 0., 0., 0.]],

        [[1., 0., 0., 0.],
         [1., 0., 0., 0.],
         [1., 0., 0., 0.],
         ...,
         [1., 0., 0., 0.],
         [1., 0., 0., 0.],
         [1., 0., 0., 0.]],

        [[1., 0., 0., 0.],
         [1., 0., 0., 0.],
         [1., 0., 0., 0.],
         ...,
         [1., 0., 0., 0.],
         [1., 0., 0., 0.],
         [1., 0., 0., 0.]],

        ...,
```

This is test_mask2:

```
tensor([[[2, 1, 1, 1],
         [2, 1, 1, 1],
         [2, 1, 1, 1],
         ...,
         [2, 1, 1, 1],
         [2, 1, 1, 1],
         [2, 1, 1, 1]],

        [[2, 1, 1, 1],
         [2, 1, 1, 1],
         [2, 1, 1, 1],
         ...,
         [2, 1, 1, 1],
         [2, 1, 1, 1],
         [2, 1, 1, 1]],

        [[2, 1, 1, 1],
         [2, 1, 1, 1],
         [2, 1, 1, 1],
         ...,
         [2, 1, 1, 1],
         [2, 1, 1, 1],
         [2, 1, 1, 1]],

        ...,
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is applying a [lookup table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lookup_table) to the target labels.
This can be done fairly easily:

```py
In []: orig_target = torch.randint(0, 3, (3,4)); orig_target
Out[]:
tensor([[2, 1, 2, 1],
        [2, 2, 1, 2],
        [1, 2, 0, 0]])

# define the lookup table: 0 -> 2, 1 -> 0, 2 -> 1:
In []: lut = torch.tensor([2, 0, 1])

# apply the lookup table
In []: lut[orig_target]
Out[]:
tensor([[1, 0, 1, 0],
        [1, 1, 0, 1],
        [0, 1, 2, 2]])
```

**Update:**

if you want to peemute the *channels* of the mask:

```
per_target = orig_target[..., lut]
```

Comment: My mask values changed, but when I try to visualize it: maks[:, :, CLASS_NUM] order stays the same. Do you know why this could happen?

Comment: @Alice you need to assign the output of the `lut`: `new_target = lut[orig_target]`

Comment: I did that, but the plt.imshow() shows masks in the same previous order

Comment: @Alice that's odd. can you make a small example?

Comment: Thanks a lot! You saved me.